# Why is this question off-topic?

Tags: support, closed-questions

The question is exactly about blender not recognizing my keyboard. Why is it off-topic? If it's not about blender... then it's about what?

[No hotkeys working at all in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45352/no-hotkeys-working-at-all-in-blender)

Comment: There's reason added in the closing description - "This question appears to be about an issue caused by a bug in Blender" and link to [answer for handling bugs](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports) because chances are this problem is caused because of this reason.